# Open another wx.python frame cause the main UI to be blocked

Tags: python-3.x, wxpython

I am trying to open another wx frame from a main frame UI. I followed the example shown here: https://wiki.wxpython.org/CallAfter but my main UI is still blocked.

Here is the event listener on the main UI:

```
def testShowGUI(self):
    # This process is a long one
    # It uses the vtk to read point cloud file and reconstruct the surface
    file = "cache/d9c5e8ef-7b7f-485e-8fc8-23098c32afcb.ply"
    reader = vtk.vtkPLYReader()
    reader.SetFileName(file)
    reader.Update()
    delaunay = vtk.vtkDelaunay2D()
    delaunay.SetAlpha(0.1)
    delaunay.SetTolerance(0.0001)
    delaunay.SetOffset(1.25)
    delaunay.BoundingTriangulationOff()
    delaunay.SetInputData(reader.GetOutput())
    delaunay.Update()
    #Once finish reading and processing the point cloud, pass to the next function for rendering
    wx.CallAfter(self.AfterProcess, delaunay)

def AfterProcess(self, data):
    meshVisGui = MesVisGUI.MeshVisGui(data)
    meshVisGui.Show()

def OnEnter(self, event):
    #Event listener when user click on Enter button
    my_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.testShowGUI)
    my_thread.start()
```

The code for the separate frame is as below:

```
class MeshVisGui(wx.Frame):
  SPACING = 4
  def __init__(self, delaunay, parent=None):
    self.delaunayData = delaunay
    self.title = "Mesh Visualization"
    wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, -1, self.title)
    self.Initialize()

  def Initialize(self):
    self.panel = wx.Panel(self, -1, size=(600, 400), style=wx.BORDER_RAISED)
    self.widget3d = wxVTKRenderWindowInteractor(self.panel, -1)
    self.widget3d.Enable()
    self.render = vtk.vtkRenderer()
    self.render.SetBackground(params.BackgroundColor)
    self.widget3d.GetRenderWindow().AddRenderer(self.render)
    self.interactor = self.widget3d.GetRenderWindow().GetInteractor()
    self.interactor.GetInteractorStyle().SetCurrentStyleToTrackballCamera()
    self.axesWidget = utils.createAxes(self.interactor)
    self.meshActor = utils.build_actor(self.delaunayData)
    self.render.AddActor(self.meshActor)
    self.render.ResetCamera()
    box = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
    box.Add(self.widget3d, 1, wx.EXPAND, self.SPACING)
    self.panel.SetSizer(box)
    self.Layout()
```

However, on my main UI, it is still showing a spinning icon and block the UI while it is trying to process the point cloud data. Can someone help me spot what I have done wrong?

Wxpython version: 4.0.1
Python version: 3.6.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following on from Mike Driscoll's answer and comment, here is a sample of a threaded task running from another panel.

The thread reports back to the 2nd panel (it's parent) using an event. This allows a progress bar to be updated.

The 2nd panel includes a "Cancel" option for the threaded task, whilst the main frame has a button to test if it is not frozen.

The use of `wx.GetApp().Yield()` may be slightly old fashioned but I have always found it to be reliable.

```
import time
import wx
from threading import Thread

import wx.lib.newevent
progress_event, EVT_PROGRESS_EVENT = wx.lib.newevent.NewEvent()

class ThreadFrame(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, title, parent=None):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent=parent, title=title)
        panel = wx.Panel(self)
        self.btn = wx.Button(panel,label='Stop Long running process', size=(200,30), pos=(10,10))
        self.btn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnExit)
        self.progress = wx.Gauge(panel,size=(300,10), pos=(10,50), range=300)

        #Bind to the progress event issued by the thread
        self.Bind(EVT_PROGRESS_EVENT, self.OnProgress)
        #Bind to Exit on frame close
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_CLOSE, self.OnExit)
        self.Show()

        self.mythread = TestThread(self)
        #Enable the GUI to be responsive by briefly returning control to the main App
        while self.mythread.isAlive():
            time.sleep(0.1)
            wx.GetApp().Yield()
            continue

        try:
            self.OnExit(None)
        except:
            pass

    def OnProgress(self, event):
        self.progress.SetValue(event.count)
        #or for indeterminate progress
        #self.progress.Pulse()

    def OnExit(self, event):
        if self.mythread.isAlive():
            self.mythread.terminate() # Shutdown the thread
            self.mythread.join() # Wait for it to finish
        self.Destroy()

class TestThread(Thread):
    def __init__(self,parent_target):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.parent = parent_target
        self.stopthread = False
        self.time = time.time()
        self.start()    # start the thread

    def run(self):
        # A loop that will run for 5 minutes then terminate
        while self.stopthread == False:
            curr_loop = int(time.time() - self.time)
            if curr_loop < 300:
                time.sleep(1)
                evt = progress_event(count=curr_loop)
                #Send back current count for the progress bar
                try:
                    wx.PostEvent(self.parent, evt)
                except: # The parent frame has probably been destroyed
                    self.terminate()
            else:
                self.terminate()

    def terminate(self):
        self.stopthread = True

class MyPanel(wx.Panel):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.text_count = 0
        self.parent=parent
        btn = wx.Button(self, wx.ID_ANY, label='Start Long running process', size=(200,30), pos=(10,10))
        btn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.Thread_Frame)
        btn2 = wx.Button(self, wx.ID_ANY, label='Is the GUI still active?', size=(200,30), pos=(10,50))
        btn2.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.AddText)
        self.txt = wx.TextCtrl(self, wx.ID_ANY, style= wx.TE_MULTILINE, pos=(10,90),size=(400,100))

    def Thread_Frame(self, event):
        frame = ThreadFrame(title='Threaded Task', parent=self.parent)

    def AddText(self,event):
        self.text_count += 1
        txt = self.txt.GetValue()
        txt += "More text " + str(self.text_count)+"\n"
        self.txt.SetValue(txt)

class MainFrame(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title='Main Frame', size=(600,400))
        panel = MyPanel(self)
        self.Show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MainFrame()
    app.MainLoop()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You do not need threads to open new frames / windows in your wxPython application. You just need to create a sub-class of `wx.Frame` to hold the code of your other frame. Then from your main application's frame, you can instantiate the other frame and show it. You use the same concept when you create a `wx.Dialog` or a `wx.MessageDialog`.

Here is a simple example:

```
import wx


class OtherFrame(wx.Frame):
    """
    Class used for creating frames other than the main one
    """

    def __init__(self, title, parent=None):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent=parent, title=title)
        self.Show()


class MyPanel(wx.Panel):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)

        btn = wx.Button(self, label='Create New Frame')
        btn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.on_new_frame)

    def on_new_frame(self, event):
        frame = OtherFrame(title='SubFrame', 
                           parent=wx.GetTopLevelParent(self))


class MainFrame(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title='Main Frame')
        panel = MyPanel(self)
        self.Show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MainFrame()
    app.MainLoop()
```

In this example, I set the other frame's parent to the `MainFrame` instance by using `wx.GetTopLevelParent(self)`. The benefit of setting a parent for the sub-frames is that if I close the main frame, it will cause the other frames to also be closed.

Comment: The thing is my 2nd panel does heavy task (load point clouds data, transform and display it). That was the reason I tried to make a thread. Anyway, I also tried non thread approach but it still blocked my main UI. When I tried to remove the heavy task out of the 2nd panel, the 2nd panel showed up instantly.

Comment: Alright, well the heavy task itself should go in a thread, but the wxPython code should not. It is the code that is taking a long time to run that is causing the UI to freeze up, not just the creation / showing of the frame. When you open the second frame, have it start a thread with your long running process and you can have a label or progress bar in the second frame that tells the user it is processing